# Why does getline evaluate to false when i put stringstream in it

Tags: c++, getline

```
    std::string str;
    uint food;
    fd.open("Costs.csv",std::fstream::in);
    if (!(fd.is_open())){
        return 0;
    } 
    std::getline(fd, str);
    std::getline(fd, str);
    std::stringstream strStream(str);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::getline(strStream, food, ',');
```

So, on the last one i have these error:
**error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::stringstream&, uint&, char)'

Comment: Put it another way, it's not clear why you think you can call `getline` with a stream, and integer and a character. `getline` needs a string as it's second argument.

Comment: It is, but i only started with c++ so i cant understand it, what is matching function

Comment: @игорькочнов Functions require certain **types** of arguments, otherwise the arguments don't match. In this case the problem is the second argument which should be a `std::string`.

Comment: @игорькочнов Read the string, and then convert the string to the integer you want with `std::stoi`.

Comment: Bookmark [C++ reference (cppreference.com)](https://cppreference.com/w/Main_Page), it is the best C++ reference on the net. It may seem a bit cryptic at first, but it is organized concisely based on language features. Take the time to get to know it. Understand the difference between [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [std::basic_istream::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)  Examples given for both.

Answer (score 0):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

- Parameters for getline(stream,string,char) and not
  getline(stream,uint,char).

When you encounter such error means function exists but the arguments are of wrong type or/and in wrong order.